# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-navigator 4.x and I have only one page to navigate But when I click <Button onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })}} title="Go To" /> in photos page, I got this error:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';


const NextButton = props => {

    return (

        <View>
            <Button onPress={() => {
                props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })
            }} title="Go To" />
        </View>
    );
}
export default NextButton;


import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Onboarding from "../components/Onboarding";
import Login from './../screens/Login';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Intro: Onboarding,
    Login: Login,
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NextButton` is not really a part of your navigation stack, and hence `props.navigation` will be undefined, unless you are passing it as prop from your screen, thus the error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate').

To get navigation inside your `NextButton` component, you can either pass it as a prop from the screen you are rendering your `NextButton`. Or since you are using an older version of the library, you can wrap your `NextButton` with the `withNavigation` HOC to get access to `navigation` props.

```js
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

const NextButton = props => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button 
        onPress={() => {
          props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })
        }} 
        title="Go To" 
      />
    </View>
  );
}
export default withNavigation(NextButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NavigationContainer`  instead of `createAppContainer`, I think that changed from v4 to v5.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
```